# How can I make a button that redirects to another php file

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I need to give the following table an "edit" button that redirects to a file I have called edit.php and sends some information with it. I'm basically showing a table full of movies and when they choose the edit button next to the movie of their choice, I need information about that movie to send to the next page so my edit form knows which record to edit. Can anybody show me how to do this? I'm really new to php.

thanks in advance

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Studio</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Edit</th>

    </tr>";

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo"<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td>
        <td>".$row['year']."</td>
        <td>".$row['studio']."</td>
        <td>".$row['price']."</td>
        <td>""</td>

        </tr>";
    }


    echo"</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: do you want to `POST` (with a form) or `GET` (with it in the url - ie. `edit.php?movieid=#`)?

Comment: I believe post. I have an add movie form and I"m trying to make a functional edit movie form.

Comment: Then you would need to create a `<form action="edit.php">...</form>` inside the `<td>""</td>` with the inputs/values you want and a button.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `a` tag and style it like a button -

```
<a href="edit.php?id=3" class="button-class">Edit</a>
```

CSS -

```
.button-class {
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Style the button as you want. Its just an example.

**Update**

For the code above it should be -

```
<td><a href='edit.php?id=" . $thevaluetopass . "' class='button-class'>Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: what does the id=3 portion mean? I'm not sure I understand how I can tell my edit.php file which field it should be changing

Comment: returns error
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'href' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MovieDB\baseform.php on line 46

This is the error I get with every solution I try

Comment: here's how I'm implementing: <td>"<a href="edit.php?id=3" class="button-class">Edit</a>"</td>
so if my primary key is title & year, would I use <td>"<a href="edit.php?title=$title year=$year" class="button-class">Edit</a>"</td> or something on those lines?

Comment: same error. Every different solution I try has the same error.

Comment: echo"<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td>
  <td>".$row['year']."</td>
  <td>".$row['studio']."</td>
  <td>".$row['price']."</td>
  <td>" <a href='edit.php?id=" . $row['title'] . "' class='button-class'>Edit</a> "</td>

  </tr>";

Comment: Why are you adding `"` between `<td>` & `<a`. ??

Comment: Try this - `echo "<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td> <td>".$row['year']."</td> <td>".$row['studio']."</td> <td>".$row['price']."</td> <td><a href='edit.php?id=" . $row['title'] . "' class='button-class'>Edit</a> </td> </tr>";`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Studio</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Edit</th>

    </tr>";

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo"<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td>
    <td>".$row['year']."</td>
    <td>".$row['studio']."</td>
    <td>".$row['price']."</td>
    <td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</td>

    </tr>";
}


echo"</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
        $conn->close();
        ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

create a page edit.php in which get id via $_GET["id"] and preform query 
SELECT * FROM movies where id=$_GET["id"];

Answer (score -1):

Just you need to send the primary key of the row. So that you will fetch the data regarding that primary key. Like that way

```
<a href='edit.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</a>
```

and on edit fetch the data like that way :

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

This $result variable contain all the data of that specific id. Now manipulate it according to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

I started with php a couple years ago.  This post is all too familiar.  It took me a while to find some of these things but stackoverflow is an awesome tool to learn php and MySQL.  Also check out w3schools for a lot of info on basic syntax.

I would recommend using $_GET instead of $_POST if you want to be able to send anyone a link to the specific movie.  If not, from what I have read, $_POST is at least a little more secure if you worried about people manipulating your URL to get to some other record in your database. Not that it can't be done, it's just a little harder.  An example of how both work is set up below.

Second, A friend of mine taught me this.  Split your first file into two pieces.  All the lines about the connection to the database should be in their own file (dbInfo.php). This way you can use them over and over on other pages without having to rewrite every page when you change a simple password.

dbInfo.php

```
<?php
//Great spot to put global variables for all files.


//Database information
$db_username    = "yourDBusername";
$db_password    = "yourDBPassword";
$db_db        = "databaseName";
$db_host      = "databaseURL";


function setVariables($u, $p, $d, $h){
    global $db_username, $db_password, $db_db, $db_host;
    $db_username = $u;
    $db_password = $p;
    $db_db = $d;
    $db_host = $h;
}

//Function that opens the database
function dbOpen(){
    global $db_username, $db_password, $db_db, $db_host;
    $con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
    if (!$con){
         die('Error: Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }   
    mysql_select_db($db_db, $con);
    return $con;
}

// Use this function when you need a result of anything more than one answer or element
function dbGetArray($query){
    $con = dbOpen();

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(!empty($result)){
        $return_val = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $i = 0;
            $temp = array();
            foreach($row as $key => $value){        
                if($i/2 != $key){
                    $temp[$key] = trim($value);
                }
                $i++;
            }
        array_push($return_val, $temp);
        }
        dbClose($con);
        return $return_val;
    }else{
        dbClose($con);
        return NULL;
    }
}

//This function gets just one value
function dbGetOne($query){
    $con = dbOpen();
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$result){
        echo "SERIOUS PROBLEM HERE!<br />";
        echo $query . "<br /><br />";
    }else{
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    }
    dbClose($con);
    return $row[0];
}

//Use this function to insert or update your database
function dbSimpleQuery($query){
    $con = dbOpen();
    $return = true;
    //echo $query;
    if(!mysql_query($query, $con)){
        echo "Error: An error occurred while running Simple Query:  " . mysql_error() . "<br>";
        echo "Original Query: " . $query . "<br><br>";
        $return = false;
    }
    dbClose($con);
    return $return;
}

//Bonus for you.  You can use this function to block sql injections
function SanitizeString($string){
    $con = dbOpen();

    //echo htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($string));
    return htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($string));
    dbClose($con);
}
```

Then in your second file change the top to look like this.

listMovies.php

```
<?php
    require_once('dbInfo.php');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM movies";
    $result = dbGetArray($query);

   //Helpful for debugging
   //echo $query;
?>
<html>
    <body>
       <table><tr>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Year</th>
         <th>Studio</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>

<?  // output data of each row
    if(!empty($result)) {
        foreach($result as $row) {
            echo"<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td>
               <td>".$row['year']."</td>
               <td>".$row['studio']."</td>
               <td>".$row['price']."</td>
               <td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</td>
            </tr>";
        }
    } else {
        echo"<tr><td colspan= '5'>No Results found</td></tr>";
    }  
    ?>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Then your third file would become something like this.

editMovies.php

```
<?
require_once('dbInfo.php');
//Check to see if a $_GET is set
if(isset($_GET['id']) {
    $id = SanitizeString($_GET['id']);  //This is where you stop sql injection
    $movies = dbGetArray("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id = '$id'");
    foreach ($movies as $movie) {
        $title = $movie['title'];
        $year = $movie['year'];
        $studio = $movie['studio'];
        $price  = $movie['price'];
    }
} else {
   $id= 0; //Can be used to show an 'empty results' page, because URL was messed with
}

//Check for $_POST from edit form
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Handy debugging line
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); die("</pre>");
    $id = SanitizeString($_POST['id']);
    $title = SanitizeString($_POST['title']);   
    $year  = SanitizeString($_POST['year']);
    $studio = SanitizeString($_POST['studio']);
    $price = SanitizeString($_POST['price']);

    $query = "UPDATE movies SET 
        title = '$title',
        year = '$year',
        studio = '$studio',
        price = '$price'
        WHERE id = '$id'";

    //Handy Debugging tool
    //die($query);
    dbSimpleQuery($query);
    $submitted = TRUE;
    //You could also put a redirect in here to take user back to listMovies.php
} else {
   $submitted  = FALSE;
}

?>
<html>
   <body>
<?if(!$submitted) { ?>
     <form action='editMovies.php' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?=$id?>'>
        <input type='text' name='title' value='<?=$title?>'>
        <input type='text' name='year' value='<?=$year?>'>
        <input type='text' name='studio' value='<?=$studio?>'>
        <input type='text' name='price' value='<?=$price?>'>
        <button type='submit' name='done' value='submit'>Update Info</button>
     </form>
<? } else if($submitted) { ?>
     <p>Congrats, your movie is updated</p>
<? } ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

I haven't actually run these pages to check for syntax errors, but this is how I would set them up.  Hope it helps.